# How can I install Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I just started running Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit). I logged into Google+ and went to there page to download the Hangout plug-in. It would download, but any time I tried to open the installer with the Ubuntu Software Center, I would just take me to the home page and won't install anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-talkplugin
```

<sup>Source:[LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/use-google-hangouts-directly-from-your-ubuntu-system-via-the-google-talk-plugin/)</sup>

Comment: If hangout chrome extension was previously installed and Disabled then after a reinstall it must be enabled from chrome settings ... only then will Hangout widget appear on screen top status bar

Comment: Is there any advance of using this over using the chrome extension that you can install via settings in Chromium?

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package google-talkplugin` on 16.04

Comment: @TimAbell Take a look [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_talk_plugin).

Comment: ta, found a better answer for me: just use chromium, it just works ;-)

Comment: this is not working in 16.04; it seems that ubuntu and debian are [enforcing  a different checksum](https://juliank.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/dropping-sha-1-support-in-apt/)

Comment: Is this a method for using Hangouts from the firefox browser? In Chrome/Chromium, Hangouts work out of the box, right?

Answer (score 3):

There is an amazing chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en). Try using that. Works much like an app.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal, visit the directory where your downloaded file has been placed, and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Google hangout installer file is downloaded as a .deb file.

***Install the file with following command:***

```
sudo dpkg -i [Folder]/[filename.deb]
```

***Or install with gdebi installer***

install the Gdebi installer as

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then Right click on the file and select `Open with Gdebi Installer`. Then Click on `Install`.

Comment: But that way Sofware Updater will not offer any updates for the plugin, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chromium, but this should work for Chrome as well.

Step 1: Install the [Hangouts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl?hl=en-GB) extension. This will automatically enable Chrome/Chromium to run in the background, along with the Hangouts app. You'll see both their icons on the taskbar above.

Step 2: Download the Hangouts [plugin](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin/download.html) (I don't know if this is necessary, I just did it anyway). Double click the downloaded file, and click 'Install' when Ubuntu Software Center pops up.

Step 3: Search "startup applications" in the dash, and click 'Add' in the window that pops up.

Step 4: Give it any name you like, for eg. 'chrome-startup'. In the command field, type the following:

if you use Chrome:

> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window

if you use Chromium:

> /usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-startup-window

Click Save.

Now whenever you login to your system, Chrome will start in the background, and along with it, the Hangouts app. Also, the Hangouts app won't close even if you close the browser.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the google officially release hangout_plugin in .deb file. Select your OS architecture and click on **Download Plugin** button.

[Click Here to Download](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin/download.html?platform=linux_ubuntu_x86_64)

then open your terminal and go to **(DOWNLOADED FILE PATH)** where file has been downloaded. Then install the .deb file by the given below command.

```
sudo dpkg -i file_name.deb
```